# Make a button continuously animated, useable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want my button to be continuously animated until the user touch it, here's the code

```
func animate() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.animation.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8,0.8)
    })
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.animation.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1)
    })
}
```

with a NSTimer

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("animate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The animation works well, but I can't find a way to make it clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the longer forms of animateWithDuration that takes an options parameter and specify the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option. Something like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, 
  delay: 0,
  options: .AllowUserInteraction,
  animations: 
  { () -> Void in
    self.animation.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8,0.8)
  }
  completion: nil
  );
```

(My Swift is a little rusty, but that's the idea anyway.)

Comment: Thanks it works, I was thinking of using the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option, but I was wondering how, so, thanks

Comment: No problem. You should come back and accept my answer as soon as SO will let you. That other people know that the question has an answer, and that a particular answer provides a solution to the question. It makes the site more useful as a research tool.